# How to resize image from url and upload it?

Tags: php

The code below resizes an image url. But I would like to upload this output as a image url:

```
<?php
// The file
$filename = 'http://valplibrary.files.wordpress.com/2009/01/5b585d_merry-christmas-blue-style.jpg';
$percent = 0.5; // percentage of resize

// Content type
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

// Get new dimensions
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);
$new_width = $width * $percent;
$new_height = $height * $percent;

// Resample
$image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);

// Output
imagejpeg($image_p, null, 100);
?>
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want to upload the result of `imagejpeg` to an external URL? As [phpnet](http://php.net/manual/de/function.imagejpeg.php) states, the second parameter is used to store it in a file, which you leave as `null` , and then you can upload it. Would this solve your problem?

Comment: solved. plz post your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You resize your image via:

```
imagejpeg($image_p, null, 100);
```

[Its usage is](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php):

```
bool imagejpeg ( resource $image [, string $filename [, int $quality ]] )
```

As you leave the second parameter `null`, it renders directly into the browser. You want to save it output though to a file, which you then can use to upload anywhere you want.

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to upload this output as a image url

Not very clear. Anyway, no need to "upload" the image as it exists in your server-side. You want to save it.

You used `file_get_contents($original_img)`. Now use `file_put_contents($filepath, $resized_img)`. To output the URL just echo its URL, depending on where you saved the file (or replaced it).

---

Just a quick tip, in a project of mine I'm using the class [Nimrod007/PHP_image_resize](https://github.com/Nimrod007/PHP_image_resize/blob/master/smart_resize_image.function.php) to resize images quickly platform-independent.

Answer (score 1):

just use `file_get_contents()`:

```
<?php
// The file
$filename = 'http://valplibrary.files.wordpress.com/2009/01/5b585d_merry-christmas-blue-style.jpg';
$percent = 0.5; // percentage of resize
$time = time();
$local_file = '/tmp/'.$tile.'.jpg';
$local_resized_file = '/tmp/'.$tile.'-resized.jpg';

file_put_contents($local_file, file_get_contents($filename));

// Content type
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

// Get new dimensions
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($local_file);
$new_width = $width * $percent;
$new_height = $height * $percent;

// Resample
$image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($local_file);
imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);

// Output
imagejpeg($image_p, $local_resized_file, 100);
echo file_get_contents($local_resized_file);
?>
```

Comment: Yeah. I think it's not matter.